# Searching for a story featuring a sorceror who can't touch silver and has multiple lives

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading it around 2004.

Possibly set in England.

There is magic in the world. It's a series of books, and each book is its own story featuring a different protagonist. There were at least 2 different books, but I'm not sure how many are in the series.

Each book also features a sorceror who can't touch silver. He never wanted to eat in front of other people because that required touching silverware. He eventually acquires stainless steel cutlery.

There's a character who has multiple lives (maybe 7?) and each life is tied to a match in a matchbox. That character might be the sorceror as well, but I can't remember. There's a scene where another character lights one of the matches, which causes him to catch fire and lose one of his lives. In another scene, he is impaled by a spear which caused him to die again by having a curtain rod impale him (might have been his alter-ego in another world?).

Comment: same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81466/novel-series-about-magic-users-with-seven-lives (which is a semi-hub for other questions)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The Chrestomanci series, by Dianne Wynne Jones

https://www.goodreads.com/series/43763-chrestomanci

Chrestomanci is a title for an enchanter with 9 lives.  The first book, Charmed Life, follows Cat Chant, whose lives were bound into a matchbox.  The current Chrestomanci in that book is Christopher Chant, whose story is told in the second book,  The Lives of Christopher Chant, and he is the one affected by silver.

The author is British, and most of the books are set in Britain (of some form)

Comment: Yes, that's definitely it. Thanks.

Comment: @Fodder: What? I thought it was 9? They lose them very quickly and stupidly... And it is so meaningless that there are only 9 worlds in each series.

Comment: @user21820 it is nine, like the lives of a cat.  I was being braindead

Comment: Haha no problem. =)