# Book about siblings in a magical world?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magic, childrens-novel, magical-items

Okay so the I read the story ages ago, so I barely remember any details but I'd really like to read it again.

Anyway, the story revolves around two siblings, their parents aren't present for whatever reason as far as I remember. They are in a magic universe.

One thing I remember is the plot twist was that the brother was a sorcerer but he didn't know that he was, yet his sister knew it. And somehow the sister was able to use her brother's magic for herself, she didn't have magic. She turned out to be evil I think at the end.

Another little detail in the story was that sorcerers had multiple lives likes 9 or 12. And the brother had previously lost one of his lives when he was an infant and he had drowned. I think his sister had tried to drown him, but pretended to save him later on. The sister pretty much did things like this all their lives, so before the plot twist was revealed the brother basically trusted her more than anything.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is [A Charmed Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charmed_Life_(novel)) by [Diana Wynne Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana_Wynne_Jones).  The hero, Eric (or Cat) is a an enchanter who possesses nine lives (like a cat).  He does not know it.  His sister Gwendolyn is a witch.  Cat does not realise that his sister is exploiting his lives for her own benefit.  It appears that one can gain magical power by exploiting a life.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81466/novel-series-about-magic-users-with-seven-lives/81467#81467